# Mapping multiple keys strokes to one key

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping

I'm using both Windows 7 and XP (simulatnateously on two machines) and I'm getting frustrated with the fact that both versions use different keystrokes to move up the folder hierarchy in explorer.  Windows 7 uses [Alt+Up] and XP uses [Backspace].

I've had a look around and tried [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) but as it says:

**Things that SharpKeys will not do:**

- Map multiple key presses to one key - e.g. it will not support an attempt to remap Ctrl+C to the F5 key

So, is there any solution?

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 2):

I do things like that with AutoHotkey: http://www.autohotkey.com

Have a look at the Hotkeys documentation, it's really simple: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: Hi Slacker, I downloaded AutoHotkey, but although I can map WIN+Up to backspace, I can't seem to map Alt+Up:   So:  {#Up::Backspace} works but {!Up::Backspace} doesn't (ingore the braces).  Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, been quite busy these days. If you still have this prob try it with a space between: {! UP::Backspace}

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about software, however, if you are not set on a $0 budget you could use a "[gaming](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007651+600009669+600010468&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=63&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=)" keyboard with programmable keys.

Comment: why was this downvoted? It sure is a viable option.